# problem with adding javascript to django view form update

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a django view to add an invoice to my application, that has added javascript, and it works fine.

```
<p>
    <label for="id_total_without_vat">Price</label>
    <input type="number" name="total_without_vat" step="any" required="" id="id_total_without_vat" oninput="calculateTotalWithVat()">
    <label for="id_currency_name">Currency</label>
    <select name="currency_name" id="id_currency_name" onchange="update_currency_rate()">
        <option value="NIS">NIS</option>
    </select>
    <label for="units">Units</label>
    <span id="units"></span>
    <label for="id_currency_rate">Currency Rate</label>
    <input type="number" name="currency_rate" step="any" id="id_currency_rate" value=1.00 oninput="calculateTotalWithVat()">
    <label for="nis_total">Total Price</label>
    <span id="nis_total"></span>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="id_total_vat_included">Total VAT Included</label>
    <input type="number" name="total_vat_included" step="any" required="" id="id_total_vat_included">
    <label for="id_vat_percentage">VAT Perentage</label>
    <input type="number" name="vat_percentage" step="any" value="17.0" id="id_vat_percentage" oninput="updateVat(this.value)">
    <label for="nis_total_with_tax">NIS Total With Tax</label>
    <span id="nis_total_with_tax"></span>
</p>
```

The problem is while trying to do something similar in the update view I see the oninput part of the command in the browser as text, this is the update view code:

```
<p>
    <label for="id_total_without_vat">Total without VAT</label>
    {{ form.total_without_vat }}
    <label for="id_currency_name">Currency</label>
    <select name="currency_name" id="id_currency_name" onchange="update_currency_rate()">
         <option value=" {{ form.currency_name }} "></option>
    </select>
    <label for="units">Units</label>
    <span id="units"></span>
    <label for="id_currency_rate">Currency Rate</label>
    <input type="number" name="currency_rate" step="any" id="id_currency_rate" value= "{{ form.currency_rate }}" oninput="calculateTotalWithVat()">
    <label for="nis_total">Price</label>
    <span id="nis_total"></span>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="id_total_vat_included">Price Including VAT</label>
    {{ form.total_vat_included }}
    <label for="id_vat_percentage">VAT Percentage</label>
    <input type="number" name="vat_percentage" step="any" value=" {{ form.vat_percentage }} " id="id_vat_percentage" oninput="updateVat(this.value)">
    <label for="nis_total_with_tax">Price Including Taxes</label>
    <span id="nis_total_with_tax"></span>
</p>
```

Can someone tell me why the add view works, but the update doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: try rendering the form "safe".

Try:

```
{{form.as_p}}
```

or:

```
{{form.total_without_vat | safe}}
```

Let me know if it works.